# Inserting nested Json from existing json string c#

Tags: c#, json

I was trying to insert nested Json string to existing Json string . Here's my json sample

JSON #1:

```
{
 "Products":[
  {
   productId:1,
   productName:"product1"
  } 
 ]
}
```

JSON #2:

```
{
 "Brand":[
  {
   brandId:1,
   brandName:"brand1"
  } 
 ]
}
```

Should be output

```
{
 "Products":[
  {
   productId:1,
   productName:"product1",
   "Brand":[
    {
     brandId:1,
     brandName:"brand1"
    } 
   ]
  } 
 ]
}
```

This is done thru c# code.Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jsonObj1=JObject.Parse(json1);
var jsonObj2=JObject.Parse(json2);

jsonObj1["Products"][0]["Brand"]=jsonObj2["Brand"];

string mergedJson=jsonObj1.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(mergedJson);
```

result

```
{
  "Products": [
    {
      "productId": 1,
      "productName": "product1",
      "Brand": [
        {
          "brandId": 1,
          "brandName": "brand1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Wow it works like a charm, i will just iterate this and this is what i expected .. Thankyou so much